# CUDA array filtering kernel without a for loop

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a large array `A` with `size_A` rows and 6 columns. I am going to check the 3rd element of each row, and if that is not zero, copy the row into another array `B`. Can I have the index to the entries of `B` without using a `for` loop, please see the below code?

I probably would need to define `b_ptr` somehow to make it static (similar to the what we have in C), but I think that is not allowed.

```
__global__ void filtering_kernel(float* A, int size_A, float* B, float* size_B)
{
    /*B and size_B are the outputs*/
    int b_ptr = 0;
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (x > size_A) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_A; i++)
    {
        if (A[x + 3] != 0)
       {
            B[b_ptr] = A[x + 0];
            B[b_ptr + 1] = A[x + 1];
            B[b_ptr + 2] = A[x + 2];
            B[b_ptr + 3] = A[x + 3];
            B[b_ptr + 4] = A[x + 4];
            B[b_ptr + 5] = A[x + 5];
            b_ptr += 6;
            *size_B = *size_B + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A word of advice: By my counting, you have now asked and **deleted** at least three questions on the CUDA tag. Be aware that if you keep doing this, you will receive an automatic question asking ban. Please stop doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to launch as many threads as there are elements in your array. If we assume `tid` (renamed from your `x`) ranges from `0` to `size_A * 6`, then we can remove the loop entirely. We do need to first determine what rows must be copied, so a shared array `filter` is introduced. Assuming you can fit `int[size_A]` into memory for a single block and have as many threads as entries, you can use the following code, with hints for how you might do this if `size_A` is big enough to need multiple blocks.

```
__global__ void filtering_kernel(float *A, const int size_A, const int W,
                                   float *B, int *size_B) {
    // We use this to store whether a given row is filtered,
    // and then scan this array to tell us how densely packed B is.
    extern __shared__ int filter[];
    
    // Assuming 1 block
    const int tid = threadIdx.x;
    const int offset = 0;
    // Multiblock difference
    // tid = threadIdx.x
    // offset = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    
    // Guard to ensure we are not out of range
    if (offset + tid >= size_A * W)
      return;
    const int row = tid / W;
    const int col = tid % W;
    // NOTE: You have 3 in your sample code, but the third column is 2
    const int mid = (W - 1)/2;

    // Dedicate one thread per row to check
    // whether we should filter
    if (tid < size_A) {
      // A boolean will be either 1 or 0
      // Whatever filter criterion you want.
      filter[tid] = A[offset + tid * W + mid] == 0;
    }

    // We then need to run a scan to get the cumulative sum
    // of the filtered with a dedicated thread. If we consider
    // good rows (g) and bad rows (b), for gggbbggbbggg we expect
    // 1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8
    for (int i = 1; i < size_A; i <<= 1) {
      if (tid < size_A && tid >= i) {
        filter[tid] += filter[tid - i];
      }
      __syncthreads();
    }
    __syncthreads();

    // We should then only copy if the cumulative sum increases
    // And handle for the case of the first row
    // Note: If you are thread limited, you can do multiple copies here.
    if ((row == 0 && filter[row]) || (row > 0 && filter[row] > filter[row - 1])) {
      B[offset + W * (filter[row] - 1) + col] = A[tid];
    }
    // Also set the expected size for B
    if (tid == 0) {
      *size_B = filter[size_A - 1];
      printf("size_B %d\n", *size_B);
      // Multiple blocks: size_B[blockIdx.x] = filtered[size_A - 1];
    }
    // TODO: For multiple blocks, we still need to densely pack B. (see below)
}
```

Continuing: as is, `filtered` needs to be shared across the kernel, so this only works within a single block. With multiple blocks, I would filter a portion of B per block (that is, keep the code above, changing where I note), record how much was filtered with `size_B` now being an array, cumulatively sum `size_B`, and then in-place copy B to be more dense (or download from device the dense parts from each portion using `size_B`).

From the comments, the invoking code:

```
int example(const float *arr, const size_t size_A, const size_t W ) {
    float *d_A;
    float *d_B;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, size_A * W * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, size_A * W * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemset(d_B, 0, size_A * W * sizeof(float));
    int *size_B;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&size_B, sizeof(int));


    cudaMemset(size_B, 0, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, arr, size_A * W * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    filtering_kernel<<<1, W * size_A, size_A * sizeof(int)>>>(d_A, size_A, W, d_B,
                                                              size_B);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printf("Error %s \n", cudaGetLastError());

    int result;
    cudaMemcpy(&result, size_B, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("Error %s \n", cudaGetLastError());

    return result;
}
```

Which we can then test using GTEST:

```
TEST(FILTER, ROW6) {
    size_t size_A = 100;
    size_t W = 6;
    float *arr = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * size_A * W); // initialize arr
    int expected = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_A * W; i++) {
      arr[i] = i % 4;
      if (i % W == 2 && arr[i] == 0)
        expected++;
    }
    printf("Expected: %d\n", expected);

    const int result = drt::example(arr, size_A, W);
    ASSERT_EQ(result, expected) << "Filter Kernel does not work.";
}
```

Comment: Did you allocate shared memory when calling the kernel? e.g. `filtering_kernel<<<1, 6 * size_A,  size_A>>>`

Comment: so `d_A` needs to be a pointer, not a float. The pointer you are passing will point at nothing. I'm compiling my example now and will update

Comment: Updated so that code compiles and runs, with a sample unit test. The primary miscommunication was that `size_A` is the number of rows in my example, but total number of elements in yours.

Comment: There's a limit to how many threads you can spawn per block + a limit to the amount of memory. As such you'll have to introduce multiple blocks to get this to work. My answer is already quite long, but I give you some good hints.

Comment: Using cumulative scan to compute the index for output is a smart trick!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is complicated and can't be done with CUDA in one step, you can't search for the desired rows and put them in array `B` hoping that they will be in the correct order, as CUDA kernels don't necessarily check the rows in order. However, there is a multi-step solution that can do the trick. First, you will run a kernel that will locate the zeros within the third column, whose index is 2 not 3 by the way, then mark these rows with value of `1` in an array `P`. After that, a simple `for` loop will count these locations and store them in another array `Ind`. Finally, a second kernel will copy the required rows from `A` to `B`.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void get_indeces(float* A, int* P, int size_A);
__global__ void filtering_kernel(float* A, float* B, int* Ind, int size_B);

int main()
{
    int i, size_A, size_B;
    size_t size;
    int* P, * d_P, * Ind, * d_I;
    float* A, * d_A, * B, * d_B;
    size_A = ..;  // specify number of rows of A
    A = new float[size_A * 6];
    // input values of array A
    ...
    P = new int[size_A];
    for (i = 0; i < size_A; i++)
        P[i] = 0;
    size = (uint64_t)size_A * 6 * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_A, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    size = (uint64_t)size_A * sizeof(int);
    cudaMalloc(&d_P, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_P, P, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    get_indeces<<<(int)ceil(size_A / 1024.0), 1024>>>(d_A, d_P, size_A);
    cudaMemcpy(P, d_P, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    size_B = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size_A; i++)
        if (P[i] == 1)
            Ind[size_B++] = i;
    Ind = new int[size_A];
    size = (uint64_t)size_B * sizeof(int);
    cudaMalloc(&d_I, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_I, Ind, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    B = new float[size_B * 6];
    size = (uint64_t)size_B * 6 * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_B, size);
    dim3 dimBlock(170, 6);  // to copy the full row at the same time, 6 * 170 < 1024
    dim3 dimGrid((int)ceil(size_B / 170.0), 1);
    filtering_kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_I, size_B);
    cudaMemcpy(B, d_B, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

__global__ void get_indeces(float* A, int* P, int size_A)
{
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (x < size_A && A[x * 6 + 2] == 0)   // if you want to use return, it should be "if (x >= size_A) return;"
        P[x] = 1;
}

__global__ void filtering_kernel(float* A, float* B, int* Ind, int size_B)
{
    int i;
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y;
    if (x < size_B)
        B[x * 6 + y] = A[Ind[x] * 6 + y];
}
```